# object of type 'DirectoryIterator' has no len()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create an Inception v3 CNN model. While doing so I am encountering the following error for this code: -

```
def extract_features(sample_count, datagen):
    start = dt.datetime.now()
    features =  np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 5, 5, 2048))
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count,10))
    generator = datagen
    i = 0
    for inputs_batch,labels_batch in generator:
        stop = dt.datetime.now()
        time = (stop - start).seconds
        print('\r',
              'Extracting features from batch', str(i+1), '/', len(datagen),
              '-- run time:', time,'seconds',
              end='')
        
        features_batch = base_model.predict(inputs_batch)
        
        features[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
            
    print("\n")
    return features, labels
```

```
train_features, train_labels = extract_features(1097, train_generator)
test_features, test_labels = extract_features(272, test_generator)
```

```
Error: - 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-24-d27864586d21> in <module>
    ----> 1 train_features, train_labels = extract_features(1097, train_generator)
          2 test_features, test_labels = extract_features(272, test_generator)

    <ipython-input-23-94a0a25bf25a> in extract_features(sample_count, datagen)
          9         time = (stop - start).seconds
         10         print('\r',
    ---> 11               'Extracting features from batch', str(i+1), '/', len(datagen),
         12               '-- run time:', time,'seconds',
         13               end='')

    TypeError: object of type 'DirectoryIterator' has no len()
```

TF version = 1.14.0
Python version =  3.6.9

Comment: Your problem is likely just what Python is saying it is.  `datagen` is a `DirectoryIterator` , which does not support the concept of "length".  That is, you can't call `len()` on it.  Do you believe that it should be able to return a length?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
        print('\r',
          'Extracting features from batch', str(i+1), '/', len(datagen),
          '-- run time:', time,'seconds',
          end='')
```

To this:

```
         print('\r',
          'Extracting features from batch', str(i+1), '/', len(list(datagen)),
          '-- run time:', time,'seconds',
          end='')
```

Comment: I tried the above code, but the execution is taking forever.

Comment: I have resolved the issue by updating the Keras version compatible with TF version 1.14.0. However I appreciate the help provided. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of digging I found out that the issue is with Keras compatibility with TF 1.14.0.
Keras 2.2.4 is compatible with TF 1.14.0